# SQL UNINITIALIZED Error when Executing a SQL Builder Class - MyBatis Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have created an SQL statement using myBatis SQL builder, but I am to finding documentation on how to execute the string once its created. Currently, I  have the following:

CONTROLLER:

```
@GetMapping("/simpleQuery/{schema}/{fromTable}")
    public List <Object> getAllDataFromTable (@PathVariable String schema, @PathVariable String fromTable){
        //return queryMapper.getSimpleQueryResults(schema, fromTable);
        return queryService.selectDataFromTable(schema, fromTable);
    }
```

SERVICE - where SQL string gets built

```
public List<Object> selectDataFromTable(String schema, String fromTable){
        String selectDataFromTable = new SQL(){{
            SELECT ("*");
            FROM (schema + "." + fromTable);
        }}.toString();
        return queryMapper.getSimpleQueryResults(selectDataFromTable);
    }

 System.out.println(selectDataFromTable);
```

I've printed the SQL string out to the console and it looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB.SOMETABLENAME
```

UPDATE: I have also tried building the sql string like:

```
 String selectDataFromTable = "SELECT * FROM " + schema +"." + fromTable;
```

So that the query is all one line but I still get the same results/error

MAPPER - sql string gets exectued

```
 @Select("#{sql}")
    List <Object> getSimpleQueryResults(String sql);
```

The query get executed but an error returns:

```
Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
```

So how do I get the SQL string to execute using mybatis in Springboot.

NOTE - I'm using annotation not XML.

Thank you

Comment: Try `@Select("${sql}")`. See this [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-).

Comment: That was it - thank you for the link to the FAQ.  That was helpful.